# Find occurrence count of a number in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of Excel data set up like this.

```
Items
1, 11, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 9, 12
15, 13, 4
7, 8, 9, 10, 1
14
1, 3, 7, 9
```

I want to make a count of each occurring number, so that I end up with a result like this:

```
Items   A2 Column
1           2
2           0
3           2
4           2
5           1
```

And so on. Are there any formulas I can use to count the frequency of each number?
I've tried using the COUNTIF function, but the formula will often come out as 0 because it can't read each number separately in the cells. Using a Pivot Table created the same results as well.

Comment: Are those numbers comma seperated in a cell?

Answer (score 1):

First split those integer values into their own cell:
Data>>TextToColumns>>Delimited>>Comma>>OK

Second set up a table where 1 through whatever is listed in the rows, then you can use `countif()` to get the counts.

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$8,A14)
```

Where `$A$2:$E$8` is the group of cells that was created with Text To Columns, and A14 is the first cell in your list of of 1 to whatever. Copy that down to each row in your list of 1 to whatever and you'll have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions Made:
-Your data is all in column A but in multiple rows. 
-Each cell in column A has one or more comma separated data sets (as shown above)

In Column D1 Place a Title "Items" and enter your item numbers in column D starting with D2 and continuing.

In Column E use the following Formula
    =SUM(COUNTIF($A:$A,D2&",*"),COUNTIF($A:$A,"* "&D2),COUNTIF($A:$A,"*, "&D2 &",*"),COUNTIF($A:$A,D2))

Explanation:

**COUNTIF($A:$A,D2&",*")** - finds entries for the specified item that are the first item in a data set with more than one item listed

**COUNTIF($A:$A,"* "&D2)** - finds entries for the specified item that are the the last item in a data set with more than one item listed

**COUNTIF($A:$A,"*, "&D2 &",*")** - finds entries for the specified item that are neither the first, nor the last item in a data set with more than one item listed

**COUNTIF($A:$A,D2)** = Finds entries for a specified item where the data set only contains one item.